# Can you take off from a country road in a ultralight aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, takeoff, ultralight

Can I take off from a country road in a ultralight aircraft (In the USA). I have seen resources online saying yes and no. Does it vary from state to state?

Comment: Yes you *can*.  I have.  But actually this is meant as an editing suggestion.  Did you mean can you *legally* / *in compliance with regulations*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't doing anything reckless or otherwise against regulations, the FAA doesn't care.

Your state or local regulations may prohibit it, though. For instance, it is illegal to do so from a public road in California.

Comment: While the FAA may not have any regulations about this, the state, county, municipality having jurisdiction over the road may not permit the operation of unlicensed motor vehicles.

Comment: @jwh20 Yes. How is that different than what I said in my second paragraph? Are you making a distinction that it may be illegal to use an ultralight on a public road even where it is legal to do so in a part 23 aircraft?